# What SHA2 hash function does Realm dot net use

Tags: encryption, realm, sha2

On the Realm Xamarin page it says

Realm supports encrypting the database file on disk with AES-256+SHA2 by supplying a 64-byte encryption key when creating a Realm.

Which SHA2 hashing function does it use. Is it SHA256?

Comment: Please post a comment explaining the reason for requesting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Realm uses SHA256 to validate data integrity. I am curious as to what difference this makes? Or are you just curious?

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was just curious about the standard. I understand that SHA2 is the encompassing family of functions, and was wondering which one of the family was being used.